# Just trying to display a row from a table

Tags: php

I get a warning message telling me that mysql_fetch_row expects a resource for parameter 1 and I gave it an object.

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "abc123", "profile");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = 1243433";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res); // error here
print_r($row);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're missing an `i`, I think. Do you mean to use `mysqli_fetch_row`, instead of `mysql_fetch_row` (without the i)?

Comment: -1: This is a very trivial typo that you should have been able to spot through the age-old process of _reading_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to `mysqli_fetch_row`

Answer (score 0):

You gave it an object from the `mysqli_` family of functions, yet it is a `mysql_` function.

Basic reading shows that the two are not the same.

Use the `mysqli_fetch_row` function from the same set of functions, instead.